# How to figure out http and ssl version using python

Tags: python, ssl, http2, spdy

Is there a good way in python to check if a website/url supports http2 and which SSL versions does it support.

What I am looking for is achievable by the use of commands

```
openssl s_client ­connect domain:443 ­nextprotoneg ''
```

output of this openssl command contains this line : `Protocols advertised by server: h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1` Through which I can figure out the http2 support.

```
curl -v -o /dev/null --silent https://www.example.com
```

This line -> `TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` in the output of the above command can tell me about the SSL version used.

I don't want to run these commands and parse the output because I feel there should be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Hyper](https://github.com/Lukasa/hyper) lib.

```
from hyper import HTTPConnection

conn = HTTPConnection('google.com:443')
# If request made over http/1.1 then result will be None
if conn.request('HEAD', '/') is not None:
    # Return a string identifying the protocol version used by the current SSL channel
    print(conn._sock._sck.version()) # little bit dirty, but work
```